# Create autoserial column in informix

Tags: sql, informix

is it possible to create a autoserial index in order 1,2,3,4... in Informix and what would be the syntax.  I have a query and some of my timestamps are identical so I was unable to query using a timestamp variable.  Thanks!

Comment: First duckduckgo search result: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=26528&seqNum=6

Comment: Also in the search results:  http://wiki.ispirer.com/sqlways/informix/data-types/serial

Answer (score 5):

These are the commands that I ran to add an id field to an existing table. While logged in to the dbaccess console.

```
alter table my_table add id integer before some_field;

create sequence myseq;
update my_table set id = myseq.nextval;
drop sequence myseq;

alter table my_table modify (id serial not null);
```

Thanks to @ricardo-henriques for pointing me in the right direction. These commands will allow you to run the instructions explained in his answer on your database.

Answer (score 1):

That would be the [`SERIAL` data type](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqlr.doc/ids_sqr_138.htm).

Answer (score 1):

You can use, as @RET mention the **SERIAL** data type.

Next you will struggle with the fact that you can't add a **SERIAL** column to an existing table. Ways to work around:

- Add an **INTEGER** column, populate with sequential numbers and then alter the column to **SERIAL**.
- Unload the data to a file, drop the table and recreate it with the new column.
- Create a new table with the new column, populate the new table with the data from the old, drop the old and rename the new.
  ...

Bear in mind that they may not be unique. Hence you have to create an **unique index** or a **primary key** or an **unique constraint** in the column to prevent duplicates.

Another notes you should be aware:
- **Primary key** don't allow **NULLS**, **unique index** and **unique constraints** allow (as long there is only one record), so you should specify **NOT NULL** on the column definition.
- If you use a **primary key** or a **unique constraint** you can create a **foreign key** to it.
- In **primary key** and **unique constraint** the validation of the uniqueness of the record is done in the end of the **DML**, for the **unique index** it is done row a row.

Seems you're getting your first touch with **informix**, welcome. Yes it can be a little bit hard on the beginning just remember:

- Always search before asking, really search.
- When in doubt or reached a dead end then ask away.
- Try to trim down your case scenario, built your own case the simple away you can, these will not only help us to help us but you will practice and in some cases find the solution by yourself.
- When error is involve always give the error code, in **informix** it is given at least one error code and sometimes an **ISAM** error too.

Keen regards.

Comment: Do you happen to have the query to update the table with sequential values?

Comment: @carlos-parraga I don't play with informix for a while, don't have anything at the moment. But what you can do it programatically either with SPL or something else. Or you can use the value of `ROWID` to populate that new column and when doing the `ALTER` specified with `SERIAL(n)`.